# Pause a click event until user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

After reading [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142574/how-to-pause-an-event-in-jquery)

I was wondering how to structure a preventDefault / stopPropagation that depends on a user click event, for example:

```
<html>
   <a data-handler="add_to_cart" data-item_id="5">Click</a>
</html>
```

Clicking the element currently calls the backend (by ajax) to add item 5 to the user cart. But what if I want to inject a dialog first (javascript only)

```
var template = '' +
    '<div class="dialog">' +
        '<p>Really add this item?</p>' +
        '<button>Yes</button>' +
        '<button>No</button>' +
    '</div>'

$(a).click(function(){
    # open the dialog template
    # if the correct button is clicked continue the default event
});
```

I do not want to use `confirm` or `prompt`, I am basically looking for a way to implement their functionality with my own html dialog.

Comment: You should use `confirm`, it's cross-browser, accessible, and works everywhere, including mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to accomplish this.  The two I would suggest is either overriding the prompt method ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056770/changing-the-way-a-javascript-alert-or-prompt-looks) about overriding and changing looks), or making your own dialog and monitoring the buttons on it.

Overriding:

```
function prompt() { 
    //Insert your HTML, show the dialog
}
```

Monitor another click:

```
$('#someOtherButton').click(function(){
    //Do what you want
});
```

I would suggest simply overriding `prompt()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent propagation and re-call the `click()` method from the dialog, and ask for propagation.

```
var template = '' +
    '<div class="dialog">' +
        '<p>Really add this item?</p>' +
        '<button class=correctbutton>Yes</button>' +
        '<button>No</button>' +
    '</div>'

$(a).click(function(){
    if(window.correctButtonClicked){
     return true;//continue propagation
    }
    window.clickedA=a // store current clicked object
    openDialog() 
    return false; //stop propagation
});

function openDialog(){
 //Make a dialog from the template
 $('.correctbutton').click(function(){
      window.correctButtonClicked=true;
      $(window.clickedA).click(); 
 });

}
```